# XSLT copy-of but change values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file which has non standard html elements like so:
Note: Paragraphs have been shortend.

```
                 <content>
                      Sacrifice. It's Mass Effect 3's major theme...
                      <p />
                      Mass Effect was about time and place; you d...
                      <p />
                      Mass Effect 3 is focused more on plot th...
                      <p />
                      <img url="me3_img1.jpg">Plenty of games feat...</img>
                      Like Star Wars, Mass Effect 3 is an inc...
                      <p />
                      The reapers aren't your only adver...
                      <p />
                      <img url="me3_img2.jpg">If looks could kill..</img>
                      The series' focus on player choice is as vi...
                      <p />
                      This intense narrative is met wi...
                      <p />
                      <img url="me3_img3.jpg">The sun is sett...</img>
                      These are exquis...
                 </content>
```

Each  will be a gap between the paragraphs.
Each image must appear in-between paragraphs where they apear in the content, the  must also have a caption, with the content being that between  and 
Note also that the  has a url and not a src, so this must change.

My current xslt only copy-of, and css fixes the layout, but img are not displaying because I can't change url to src, aswell as set the caption.

Please help.

Update:

```
<xsl:for-each select='./review/content/child::*'>
                          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                          <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="name()='p'">
                              <p />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="name()='img'">
                              <div class="reviewImage">
                                <img>
                                  <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./@url"/>
                                  </xsl:attribute>
                                </img>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                              </div>                                
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
```

It is not outputing any of the text(). The Images and captions are sorted now though.

Solution found:

```
                       <xsl:for-each select='./review/content/node()'>
                          <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="name()='p'">
                              <p />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="name()='img'">
                              <div class="reviewImage">
                                <img>
                                  <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./@url"/>
                                  </xsl:attribute>
                                </img>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                              </div>                                
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to copy something and change part of it, the answer is almost always to use the identity template with additional templates. `copy-of` cannot do this, and I avoid `copy-of` as much as I can.

Here is how you can do what you describe (when you say "caption", I'm not sure whether you mean `alt` or `title` attributes, so I'll use both:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content/img">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:attribute name="alt">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content/img/@url">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<content>
  Sacrifice. It's Mass Effect 3's major theme...
  <p />
  Mass Effect was about time and place; you d...
  <p />
  Mass Effect 3 is focused more on plot th...
  <p />
  <img src="me3_img1.jpg" alt="Plenty of games feat..." title="Plenty of games feat..." />
  Like Star Wars, Mass Effect 3 is an inc...
  <p />
  The reapers aren't your only adver...
  <p />
  <img src="me3_img2.jpg" alt="If looks could kill.." title="If looks could kill.." />
  The series' focus on player choice is as vi...
  <p />
  This intense narrative is met wi...
  <p />
  <img src="me3_img3.jpg" alt="The sun is sett..." title="The sun is sett..." />
  These are exquis...
</content>
```

Comment: The url is not changed yet to src.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `copy-of` is to copy content unchanged from the input tree to the output tree.

In order to change something between the input and output trees, you will want to use `apply-templates` and `template`.

If you wish to output an element on the output tree with the same name as on the input tree, but different content, you can use `copy` in your template, and fill the "copy" with the appropriate content.

Comment: How would I then split the <p /> or even keep track of where each image belongs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "split the p", `copy-of` won't do that either, but you would probably do that with a template that matches `p` and "splits" it.

Comment: You don't need to keep track of where the images belong.  By default, `apply-templates` operates on the selected nodeset in document order, so that will just happen.