# XSLT style - pattern matching multiple templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is a question about xslt 1.0 (but i've included the general xslt tag as it may apply more widely).

lets say we want to take this xml

```
<root>
  <vegetable>
    <carrot colour="orange"/>      
    <leek colour="green"/>
  </vegetable>  
</root>
```

and transform it to cook the vegetables if they are root vegetables so this..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="carrot">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="cooked">true</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="leek">    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so the xslt recursively processes the data, and when it finds multiple matching templates e.g. leek and carrot, it takes the last one, effectively overriding.

Sometimes accepted answers in this site have this style,
e.g. [XSLT copy-of but change values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634229/xslt-copy-of-but-change-values)

other answers specifically about multiple matching templates
e.g.
[XSLT Multiple templates with same match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513376/xslt-multiple-templates-with-same-match)

state

Having two templates of the same priority that match the same node is an error according to the XSLT specification

> It is an error if [the algorithm in section 5.5] leaves more than one
> matching template rule. An XSLT processor may signal the error; if it
> does not signal the error, it must recover by choosing, from amongst
> the matching template rules that are left, the one that occurs last in
> the stylesheet.

so....we can avoid this by either using priority or by matching to explicitly excluding the the overlap, something like this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()[not(self::carrot) or not(self::leek)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="carrot">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="cooked">true</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="leek">    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the feeling that lots of devs actually simply use the default fallback behaviour and let the processor use the last match, this is similar in style to pattern matching in most functional languages where the 1st match is used.

I also personally am not a fan of priority, it feels a bit like magic numbers, where i have to scan and remember the priority of the pattern matches to work out whats going on.

The approach to explicitly exclude overlaps, seems sensible, but in practice requires complex logic and creates coupling between templates, if i extend/add a new match, i potentially have to amend constrain another.

Is the above a correct summary?
Is there an accepted style (even if it contradicts the spec)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be missing the fact that there is no error in the given example, therefore the rule of applying the template that occurs last in the stylesheet is not invoked. You can verify this by switching the order of the templates and observing that the result remains unchanged.

There is no error because the identity transform has a priority of -0.5 while the specific templates have a priority of 0.

Read the entire specification for conflict resolution:
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#conflict

Comment: how doubly odd....what makes a template the identify transform? i.e. how does the processor know its the identity template?

Comment: ...."Otherwise, if the pattern consists of just a NodeTest preceded by a ChildOrAttributeAxisSpecifier, then the priority is -0.5."""

Comment: hmmm...ok....well it was worth asking because ive never realised that....I must admit I don't like the fact it secretly has special priority, I'd prefer everything to have the same priority and then either match the 1st (like most fp languages) or the last (like the recovery mechanism)

Comment: The processor does not know it's the identify transform template. It looks at the pattern and sees that it *"just tests for nodes with particular types"*. I am not sure what you mean by *"secretly has special priority"*. The priorities are not secret nor special.

Comment: well before i knew i suspected that all templates had the same priority...rather like a match case pattern patch in ML/OCAML/Haskell/F#/Scala etc....you just match until one hits..then i discovered priority...but i still thought there would be a single default priority, having rules around priorities is a bit 'special' and 'secret'....unless u like reading PL specs

Comment: How else would you learn?

Comment: is that rhetorical (i.e. ironic)? most people don't learn programming (or natural) languages from specs. The pattern matching semantics in XSLT isnt obvious (to me) because it doesnt follow the usual idioms of other languages....priority feels 'special' to XSLT, and the implicit rules thus 'secret' (and written in holy texts).

Comment: an analogy would be learning arithmetic, u don't seem many 5 year olds grappling with peano's axioms

Comment: I didn't mean to be ironic. I really don't know how else you could learn the language - unless you have a really good book. Even then I would recommend keeping the XSLT and XPath specifications close at hand and consult them whenever in doubt.